# Is it possible to add custom data to the notification body(links, buttons, ...)

Tags: java, notifications, vaadin

I want to add some components to the body of vaadin notification. It can be button or link.
So, is it possible and how can I do it? 
I am using vaadin 6.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't add custom components to stock Vaadin notifications.

There are addons built specifically for this purpose, though.

[**Notifique**](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/notifique) is a really good one and you craft it to suit to a lot of different scenarios. You can also add custom layouts and components to it's content.